# Collapsed jQuery Accordion

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, jquery-ui-accordion

I am using jQuery accordion. I want to set accordion as **expanded** or **collapsed** dinamically.

For this I wrote this:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $( "#_title_${sec_id}_id" ).accordion({
         active: ${open},
          collapsible: true,
          heightStyle: "content"          
        });
      });
</script>
```

But if `${open}` is **true** accordions are **collapsed**, and if `${open}` is **false** they are **collapsed again**.

Is this a bug Or I am mistaken somewhere?

Is there a solution?

Comment: You have set active as false by default but it should be executed only after certain condition satisfies...

Comment: Yes, I copy the wrong code.. Now I edit it...

Comment: jsbin would be good here http://jsbin.com/

Comment: @Teo: Plz do post the right code also.

Comment: This is the right code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [accordion api](http://api.jqueryuhttp://forum.jquery.com/topic/expand-all-zones-for-an-accordioni.com/accordion/#option-active) active is meant for "Which panel is currently open." , it takes false (to collapse all) or other options are numeric like 1, 2 to active either the first or second respectively

Logically it will not be a bug because as accordion is meant to collapse the menu. You can post to their forum for better clarification

I tried using `active: false/true` but they both behave the same. http://jsfiddle.net/raunakkathuria/sc7uL/1/

See this blog for explanation regarding this http://forum.jquery.com/topic/expand-all-zones-for-an-accordion

Comment: Have added the blog where they said that they don't support this feature.